# send params to node server using cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm trying to upload file and send params in the same request it's possible with filetransfer but i have a problem in the server side the req.body is always empty i'm using formidable module

this is the client side

```
        upload = function (imageURI) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            options = new FileUploadOptions();

        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = 'filename.jpg'; // We will use the name auto-generated by Node at the server side.
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;


        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;


        alert(imageURI);
        ft.upload(imageURI, serverURL + "/upload",
            function (e) {
                getFeed();
            },
            function (e) {
                alert("Upload failed");
            }, options);
    },
```

this is the server side

> var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

```
 form.parse(req, function(error, fields, files) {
      console.log(req.body.value1);


console.log("Traitement terminé");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem i had to replace

> console.log(req.body.value1);

by

> console.log(fields.value1);